# Why this writes frequently? Failed to start monitoring 0A3C202B1601A00A

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, galaxy

I reintall windows in this week and i reinstall AVD and SDK and unzip the eclipse again, but when i connect the Galaxy phone to computer, eclipse has error, first in console tab in eclipse writes:

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\MOBILE PROGRAMMING\android-sdk\android-        sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed."
```

and then writes "Failed to start monitoring 0A3C202B1601A00A" frequently.

when i disconnect the phone of computer, this message(Failed to start monitoring 0A3C202B1601A00A) be removed. if i try to run the program with emulator, the error writes in console tab:

```
No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a            device or starting an AVD.
```

I dont know what should i solve this problem. Please help me.

Cheers.

Comment: I run the program again, when i connected the phone, eclipse writes "Failed to start monitoring 0A3C202B1601A00A" and when disconnected eclipse not any writes but when i run the program with emulator after minutes in the console tab writes "Failed to install example.exe on device emulator-5554!" Why?? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this post. [Failed to start monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980767/failed-to-start-monitoring-and-not-run-the-program-why)

The solution for me was actually to use a different USB port.