# Failed to start monitoring and not run the program. Why?

Tags: android, android-emulator, monitoring, galaxy

I reinstalled Windows 7 last week and unzipped Eclipse and reinstalled the SDK again, but I didn't run the program in Eclipse. When I connect the Galaxy phone to my computer, Eclipse shows an error and frequently writes in the console tab `Failed to start monitoring 0A3C202B1601A00A`. After a while, Eclipse qill show an Android Device Chooser window. I can't select `0A3C202B1601A00A`.

I use ADB and i write adb address and adb devices in cmd, cmd writes deamon not running.

When I disconnect the phone from my computer and I want to run the program with an emulator, the program won't run and when I write adb devices in cmd, cmd nothing written.

Why? Please help me :(

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Kill the adb task via task manager. Then, type at the command prompt: `adb devices`

This should restart the adb daemon and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Re-install the windows driver for your galaxy phone. Its possible that it is corrupted. I had to re-install mine just to get the OS to detect my phone a while back.

Also check the USB debugging mode the phone is using. Sometimes the phone can go into a storage-only mode.

Comment: Thanks for answer. USB debugging mode is enable. I can't find the driver else for my phone .The phone is Galaxy nexus phone. Please help me.

Comment: I run the program again and the Eclipse shows a new error. In console tab writes "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.You must restart adb and Eclipse.Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\MOBILE PROGRAMMING\android-sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.". In cmd when i write adb devices, cmd writes "*daemon not running.starting it now on port 5037* ADB server didn't ACK *failed to start daemon* error: cannot connect to daemon".

Comment: Have you tried looking for a driver on the [samsung website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/SGH-i907) ? Look for one that allows you to install kies. That comes packaged with a driver too.

Comment: Thanks. I use a different USB port and when i run the program, the program runs in my phone. Thank u.

Comment: For the sake of bringing it to a solution, did you use a different type of USB port ? Just curious as to what could have caused the problem.

Comment: Yes. I use a different type of USB port. When i use a USB3 port, the program not run and when i write adb devices in cmd, cmd writes that my phone is offline. I use a USB2 port and the program was run and cmd writes status my phone is device but my program with emulator not run and in console tab writes "Failed to install .apk ". Why?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to wait for half an hour after which everything works.
But this was the first start up of my 'hello world' app on my Android phone.
The IDE ran on Ubuntu linux.